# the default android studio program doesn't work when i run it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to run an empty app (the deafult one with hello world) and I get errors when I try to run the app.

The steps I performed are:

- Created the empty project:
- Opened the Nexus S API P emulator.
- pressed the run button
- waited for the app to start by itself (it opened and closed immediately)
- reopened the application from the menu with the title

"MyCollege keeps stopping"
"App info"
"Close app"

do you have any idea how to fix this?

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycollege">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCollege">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mycollege;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is my error in run:

```
03/21 14:17:28: Launching 'app' on Nexus S API P.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.mycollege/com.example.mycollege.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 16194 on device 'Nexus_S_API_P [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/ample.mycolleg: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/ample.mycolleg: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (blacklist, reflection)
I/WindowInsetsCompat: Could not retrieve WindowInsets.CONSUMED field
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field CONSUMED in class Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (declaration of 'android.view.WindowInsets' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.createWindowInsetsInstance(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1071)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.<init>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1040)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Builder.<init>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:860)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.<clinit>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:55)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mycollege.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
W/ample.mycolleg: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/WindowInsets;-><init>(Landroid/graphics/Rect;)V (blacklist, reflection)
I/WindowInsetsCompat: Could not retrieve WindowInsets(Rect) constructor
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.graphics.Rect]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.createWindowInsetsInstance(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1092)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.<init>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1040)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Builder.<init>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:860)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.<clinit>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:55)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mycollege.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mycollege, PID: 16194
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycollege/com.example.mycollege.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mycollege.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.mycollege.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:64)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(WindowInsetsCompat.java:113)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$BuilderImpl20.build(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1058)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Builder.build(WindowInsetsCompat.java:996)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.<clinit>(WindowInsetsCompat.java:56)
            ... 29 more
```

I used Android Studio 4.1.3 with an "Empty Activity" template

Comment: "Created the empty project" -- which version of Android Studio did you use, and which project template did you use. I almost always use the "Empty Activity" template.

Comment: I used Android Studio 4.1.3 with an "Empty Activity" template

Comment: I tried that combination and had no problems running on an Android 9 emulator. I tried both Java and Kotlin, with 23 as the `minSdkVersion`. I also do not see any issues in the issue tracker that seem to be related to your symptoms. You might try creating a brand-new project and see if the problems are seen there as well. If they are, [file an issue against Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) with the project attached as a ZIP file, showing your stack trace and explaining all of the steps that you took to create the project.

Answer (score 0):

So this is happening because of any logical error in your code which is related to androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout

Here's something you can do

1. check what's at line 17 in activity_main.xml , try removing that component or that particular line and see if it works.
2. make sure your app's theme inheriting from Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps but unfortunately it still doesn't work, I edited the post with all the new information